# ARM code giving an illegal instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm getting an illegal instruction error when running my code. There are no compilation errors - but even when I debug it just gives me this error.

Here is the code that I am using so far:

```
.global .fopen
.global .fclose
.global getc

.data
    fin: .word 0x00
    r: .asciz "r"
    format: .asciz "%d\n"
.global main
main:
    PUSH {R1}
    LDR R0, [R1, #0x04]
    LDR R1, =r
    BL fopen
    LDR R1, =fin
    STR R0, [R1]
    POP {R1}
endl:
    LDR R1, =fin
    LDR R0, [R1]
    BL fclose
_exit:
    MOV R7, #1
    MOV R0, #0
    SWI 0
```

Comment: You're probably on a sane system where .data sections get marked as no-execute...

Comment: @Notlikethat even when i remove .data it doesn't work and gives the same error. I'm using a Raspberry Pi

Comment: What @Notlikethat is hinting at is that you need to write `.text` before `main:`, to indicate to the assembler/linker/loader that the following is to be interpreted as executable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With credit to @EOF and @Notlikethat:

> ... you need to write .text before main:, to indicate to the assembler/linker/loader that the following is to be interpreted as executable code. 
>   - @EOF

Thanks a lot guys!